# How to add missing xml attribute to specific view in android studio automatically

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, attributes, imageview

I want to add specific XML attribute for the view in android layout file.

I am getting lint message to add contentDescription to ImageView for more 400 ImageView and I don't want to add it manually by going to each ImageView XML tag. so is there any way to automatically add missing attribute with its value in android studio.

Comment: I am sure you would want to insert it one at a time because each ImageView will have different description. right?

Comment: Those messages aren't problem. Are there any reason to want this?

Comment: Right. contentDescription is just for Accessibility purposes. Means, you would want to add this if you want your app to be usable for people with disabilities, such as visually impaired.

Comment: @user1506104 If I want to add same description to all ImageView then?

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the `layout` folder, click `Replace in Path`. Then in string to match put in

`<ImageView`

then in string to replace field, put

`<ImageView android:contentDescription="yourText"`

Then, press `Find`. Finally press `All Files`.

Moxdroid:
**And finally Reformat and Rearrange the code.**

Me:
You don't need to reformat. Your ImageView output will look like this

`<ImageView android:contentDescription="yourText"
            android:id="@+id/img_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:background="@drawable/back_selector" />`

Unless OCD kicks in, this is totally fine i guess.